# add a url param with nginx for googlebot

Tags: http, nginx, url-rewriting, bots

I want to add a url param,  "googlebot=yes" when the user-agent requesting a page on my site is Googlebot.

How do I do this in nginx?

Comment: thanks mohammad, this is so that my caching layer will treat them separately, else my googlebot specific stuff will be served to users.

Comment: also what kind of different, google bots don't like this, not all google bots use a google bot user agent, they try to detect if you're changing content for them, this is called cloaking, your site gets penalties for doing that. check this link https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66355

Comment: Thanks, I heard about the cloaking.    But I'd still like to treat them differently.